# How to restore the transformations after a resize

Tags: javascript, processing.js

I am working with Processing.js (version 1.4.8).

I have 5 white points, which coordinates I chose specifically. The black dot marks the center of the sketch! I want to be able to translate and scale my sketch. ALSO, I want it to occupy the whole window.

```
var mapWidth, mapHeight, canvas, pjs, centerX, centerY;
var points = [[100, 100], [300, 100], [100, 300], [300, 300], [200, 200]];

var setSize = function() {
  mapWidth = $(window).outerWidth();
  mapHeight = $(window).outerHeight();
  if (pjs) {
    pjs.size(mapWidth, mapHeight);
  }
};

var clear = function() {
  pjs.background(200);
};

var drawPoint = function(coordinates) {
  var radius = 30;
  pjs.ellipse(coordinates[0], coordinates[1], radius, radius);
};

var drawPoints = function() {
  pjs.fill(255);
  points.map(function(point) {
    drawPoint(point);
  });
};

var calculateCenter = function() {
  centerX = Math.floor(mapWidth / 2);
  centerY = Math.floor(mapHeight / 2);
};

var drawCenter = function() {
  calculateCenter();
  var radius = 10;
  pjs.fill(0);
  pjs.ellipse(centerX, centerY, radius, radius);
  console.log("center", centerX, centerY);
};

var move = function() {
  pjs.translate(200, 300);
  redraw();
};

var zoomIn = function() {
  pjs.scale(2, 2);
  redraw();
};

var draw = function() {
  clear();
  drawPoints();
  drawCenter();
};

var redraw = function() {
  clear();
  draw();
};

var addEvent = function(object, type, callback) {
  if (object == null || typeof object == "undefined") return;
  if (object.addEventListener) {
    object.addEventListener(type, callback, false);
  } else if (object.attachEvent) {
    object.attachEvent("on" + type, callback);
  } else {
    object["on" + type] = callback;
  }
};

$(function() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("map");

  setSize();

  var pjsRun = function(processingjs) {
    pjs = processingjs;
    pjs.setup = function() {
      pjs.size(mapWidth, mapHeight);
      draw();
    };
  };
  var p = new Processing(canvas, pjsRun);

  addEvent(window, "resize", function(event) {
    setSize();
    redraw();
  });
});
```

Until here, everything is fine, as you can see in [this](https://codepen.io/joaorodr84/pen/JyWRJP) CodePen.

[image]

I want to be able to resize the window AND keep the transformations (translations, scales, ...) that I had already performed.

Please, open the CodePen and try to reproduce this weird behaviour:

1) Perform one (or two) transformation(s) using the top-right buttons

The map is translated by 200 to the right and 300 downwards.

[image]

Everything OK by now...

But the problem arises now.

2) Resize the window

The five points are again where they were before the "translate" operation.

[image]

So... Again... Is there a way to resize without losing all the transformations that had been performed?

Thanks

Comment: Not exactly related, but why are you shimming event listener attachment when you're using jQuery?

Comment: Because, I thought that the problem might be related to the jQuery "resize" event. But it is not, and I forgot to change it back.

Answer (score 1):

Like you've discovered, it appears as though calling the `size()` function resets the transformation matrix. The short answer to your question is that you need to keep track of the transformations, and then apply them whenever you draw something.

The longer answer to your question is that you're using Processing.js a little bit differently than people typically use it. You've left out the `draw()` function (note that your `draw()` function is **not** the `draw()` function that's automatically called 60 times per second) and are trying to code event handlers yourself. This disconnect is why you're having issues.

If I were you, I'd start with a more basic sketch that starts out using Processing's built-in `draw()` function. Write code that draws the scene every frame. Make sure you set the translation and scale every frame. Here's an example:

```
var draw = function() {
  scale(scaleX, scaleY);
  translate(translateX, translateY);

  background(200);
  fill(255);
  points.map(function(point) {
    ellipse(coordinates[0], coordinates[1], 30, 30);
  });

  fill(0);
  ellipse(width/2, height/2, 10, 10);
};
```

Then setup event listeners that change the values of `scaleX` and `scaleY` as well as `translateX` and `translateY`. Let Processing handle the rest.

Comment: Thanks. I have a few questions. 1) I want a rather static sketch. When I perform changes, I explicitly call a redraw method. Do I have to draw the sketch 60 times per second? Or can I avoid this "loop"? 2) How do I keep track of all the transformations? Do I save only the LAST translation `translateX = 100` or do I add them up `translateX += 100`? 3) Can you build me an example with the Processing.js draw function, please? I still haven't really understood how it works. ... Thanks a lot!

Comment: @joaorodr84 You can use the `noLoop()` function to avoid calling the `draw()` function 60 times per second. You keep track of the transformations using variables, and yes you'd have to keep track of whatever the "total" transformation is. This example already uses the Processing.js `draw()` function. If you have follow-up questions, please post them in their own question posts with an updated [mcve]. Good luck.

Comment: Kevin Workman... Hi. I edited the question. It seems to be working with the Processing.js draw function. But I've still got another problem. Could you please see my UPDATE 1 in the post? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @joaorodr84 Please post new questions in their own question posts with their own updated [mcve]. Stack Overflow isn't really designed for new questions added in edits. Also please note that the code you post should be a small example that we can copy and paste to run, not your full program.

Comment: I think I can't make the example shorter, because moving (using the arrows) before zooming is necessary to reproduce the problem. But, you are right. I just posted it as a new question: [How to recenter after a zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45574552/how-to-recenter-after-a-zoom). Thank you.